# Store a session objects values into a database?

Tags: c#, asp.net, sql-server, session

I am creating a website. It has a database and I'm trying to work with the `Member` table.

On the page, I asked the user to fill out some basic information to become a member, once the submit button is clicked, I stored these information into a session object (which has `MemberID`, `LastName`, `FirstName`, and such) I was wondering how I can store all information in this session object to the `Member` table in the database? (The table has already been created)

Also, I would like to know when an existing member logs in. How can I get information from the database and display on the webpage (in case the member wants to edit his profile).

I am using Visual Studio 2010, coding in aspx, C#, and SQL database.

----- edit 8:13pm 6/17/2012 -----

I might not be clear when I first explain my problem.

I have a `Member` class in the .cs file, which has those variables states above. I created a new entry for a new member (on the web page), then store the object in session.

Comment: You might find this built in feature of ASP.Net useful - Memberhip: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/yh26yfzy.aspx

Comment: @dash thanks! but this is a project about web & database programming, the prof wants us to start building from low level, that's why I created a database of my own and try not to use too much of the built-in features of visual studio @.@ my problem right now is to throw this one session to the database and store it 0.0" Thanks for the link anyway :)

Comment: There is no such thing as a **SQL database** -- SQL is just the *Structured Query Language* - a language used by many database systems, but SQL is not a database product...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Personally I don't see the need to use ASP.Net session state, based on what you've said.

I presume you already have a button click handler to assign the control values of the submitted form to your `Member` object, and then you assign `Member` to session. But instead, this is the point at which you want to store `Member` to the database and not both with session.

So pass the class instance to a method which will make use of ADO.Net. In the method create a SqlConnection object, and a SqlCommand object. There are more generalised versions but I'm assuming your using sql server. To your SqlCommand object add command text which should be an update SQL statement, and parameters. Finally execute the command to store to the database.

Working through this introduction site should explain the finer detail. http://www.csharp-station.com/Tutorial/AdoDotNet/lesson01

Reading the user information back is similar except you start to use a SqlDataReader. Again that article will help.

Of course there is something called Entity Framework Code First which takes away all the plumbing between your code and the database.

Answer (score 0):

Consider creating a data access layer and use this to persist data to the database.

Comment: how would I do that?

I have this in my MemberProfile.aspx page so it store in a session. I don't know how to store it into the database. (Member object has a lot of variables such as MemberID, FirstName...)
//store the Member object in the session
Session["member"] = m;

I have a .mdf file for the SQL database, and the table name is Member.